# iOS - Access Navigation Controller in AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have built my app using Storyboards. I have a UITabBarController and a NavigationController embedded it that.
I am trying to customise my app with tint colors and I have managed to set a custom color for the Tabbar. I was able to access the tabbar from the rootViewController, however I cannot get access to the navigation bar. Is there anyway that I can easily access this?
Sample of my AppDelegate code is below.

Thanks

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:  (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController;
    UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
    [tabBar setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.4 green:0.522 blue:0.129 alpha:1];

    //This bit doesnt work
    UINavigationController *navCon = self.tabBarController.navigationController;
    navCon.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.384 green:0.259 blue:0.161     alpha:1];

    return YES;    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using navigation controllers, would expect them to embed the view controllers that are managed by the tab bar controller.

Try `NSLog(@"%@", [self.tabBarController viewControllers]);` and see whether it lists navigation controllers or your custom controller.  For example, I created two view controllers that are triggered by my tab bar, one with and one without navigation and the above line shows:

```
 (
     "<UINavigationController: 0x6a35f20>",
     "<SecondViewController: 0x6a39500>" )
```

So, I could get mine as `[[self.tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0]`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you did no work with IBOutlet's, I suggest you maybe use them along with the XIB file. For example, In the header file:

```
IBOutlet UINavigationBar *aNavBar;
```

And then in the .m, switch:

```
UINavigationController *navCon = self.tabBarController.navigationController;
navCon.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.384 green:0.259 blue:0.161     alpha:1];
```

With:

```
[aNavBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.384 green:0.259 blue:0.161     alpha:1]];
```

And there you go! I made this quick, so tell me if it works or not.
-***Justin A.***